# "Unable to connect to the remote server" - works at home, doesn't work at work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webrequest

I have this 1-line request and it is failing:

var reader = XmlReader.Create(address);

However, I can open it in the browser no problem.

At home everything's working fine, at work, I get this problem.

**Any idea what's wrong?**

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does your work use a web proxy?

Comment: ^^ as above re:proxy, my best guess would be your proxy requires authentication. You could probably spoof an Identity using a basic http client implementation.

Comment: Yep, there is a proxy

Comment: Adding 
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
        </defaultProxy>
to     <system.net> solves the problem :))